# Webkit Desktop Browser for iOS Development

Tags: jquery, ios, browser, mobile-safari, jqtouch

Currently i am trying to get into jQuery and jQtouch for the development of web-based applications for the iOS. However i am forced to "debug" the application on my device which is somehow tedious. Therefore, i want to know which browser is the most suitable on to test my application on my desktop. It should be lightweight and it would be cool if it is portable. Any recommendations that you might give me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Weinre](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-weinre)

http://jsconsole.com/remote-debugging.html

I mostly use safari user-agent to switch into mobile safari to test few features.

[image]

Comment: Is this Mac only, because i am developing on Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: useragent switch can be enabled from windows safari as well. But I've have not tested it.

Comment: I guess you can run this as jar on windows - refer - https://github.com/pmuellr/weinre/issues/24

Comment: +1 for Safari! Unfortunately, there is very limited support to debug on the device itself

Answer (score 0):

I've completed a couple of mobile web assignments recently, and in both instances I did a lot of the up-front development testing in desktop Safari, before checking stuff out on the devices themselves (I also use a Mac, so I can use the iOS emulator, but that's beside the point for you). This worked pretty well to be honest, but if I was doing extensive debugging on the device itself, I'd look at Weinre too (as linked in the answer above).

Answer (score 0):

You could try: http://www.electricplum.com/studio.aspx

It used to have a lite free version but this is no longer available. They do have a 7 day trial. It's a pretty feature rich application.